# Adding days to DATE from DATETIME from database

Tags: php, html

How to add days from database to datetime fetched from database? I tried using 
`$expiry = date(''.$bads_date.'', strtotime('+'.$bp_validity.' days')); ?>` but its not working as required. Am I missing something here?

Here,

$bads_date = 2017-04-08 17:39:39 (from database), and

$bp_validity = 7 (from database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be:

```
$expiry = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($bads_date. '+'. $bp_validity.' days'));
```

Comment: Thanks.. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know!